# How to set permission in custom drupal module in Drupal7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have created a custom Drupal7 form module , but I want to show the form to the authenticated users only . I want to create the module likewise that it could have check-box options in the `people->permission` section  from where I could set the permission for this module for all type of users .Here is the `menu_hook`

```
function form_example_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['examples/form-example'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => 'Example Form', //page title
    'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
    'page arguments' => array('form_example_form'), //put the name of the form here
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );
  return $items;
}
```

I am new in drupal so any help regarding this would be appreciable.If someone could write down the `hook_permission` rather than giving examples then it would be a great help.

Comment: This shlod be moved to Drupal stackexchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the implementation of `hook_permission`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function form_example_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer your module' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer permission for your module'),
      'description' => t('Some description that would appear on the permission page..'),
    ),
  );
}
```

And you have to give the key of the returned array (`administer your module`) to `access arguments` in the implementation of `hook_menu`
So, your hook_menu implementation would become:

```
function form_example_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['examples/form-example'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => 'Example Form', //page title
    'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
    'page arguments' => array('form_example_form'), //put the name of the form here
    'access arguments' => array('administer your module'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Note that you'll have to flush the cache after you change anything in `hook_menu`. You can do it from `admin/config/development/performace/`

Comment: your code working fine and prom permission section I have checked the permission for authenticate users only but the link for the form still showing for anonymous users as well

Comment: @user3170182 you have to remove the `'access callback'` key completely from the `hook_menu` implementation, because that is giving access to everyone (TRUE). See the edit. Remember to flush cache again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. After adding this clear your cache and go to the people->permission and from there you could set permission for users .

```
function form_example_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer my module' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer my module'),
      'description' => t('Perform administration tasks for my module.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: but the link is showing in anonymous user though I give permission to the authenticate users only